# qgis printcomposer: can I wrap text in attr table?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have some longish text attributes and when I try and put these on the map using the attribute table they get truncated.  Is there a way to get these long lines wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently - there's some outstanding feature requests for this:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10273
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8006